# Can Tillandsia Antonio be grown as an air plant without soil?

Tags: houseplants, tillandsia

I bought it rooted in soil, though as other air plants it is watered into the leafs. Can I remove it from its pot?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the entire genus Tillandsia is often referred to as "air plants," some members of the genus prefer to grow on the ground rather than hanging in midair. Here's a good article that distinguishes between "[Tillandsia air plants](https://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/air-plants)" and "[green Tillandsias](https://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/tillandsia-cyanea-lindenii)" and explains how to care for them differently.

Most sources sell Tillandsia Antonio as a potted plant rather than mounted or suspended, which seems to imply they prefer to be on the ground. However, I found one supplier that says you can mount a *well-established* Tillandsia Antonio.

> Tillandsia ‘Antonio' is an exceptional species that can be grown terrestrially in a well drained epiphyte mix. It grows about 10" tall and 10" wide with a beautiful flattened pink branching bloom spike. These slow growers...will take years before becoming blooming age. The plants...can be grown terrestrially in a well-drained epiphyte mix but they can be mounted and grown epiphytically as they become well established. ([source](https://www.blackjungleterrariumsupply.com/Tillandsia-Antonio_p_3445.html))